# Rails select helper - Default selected value, how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is a piece of code I'm using now:

```
<%= f.select :project_id, @project_select %>
```

How to modify it to make its default value equal to to `params[:pid]` when page is loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you want a default project selected when the page is loaded, if :project_id isn't set, or if you want to return the value of the select in the params hash as :pid.

Answer (score 243, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<%= f.select :project_id, @project_select, :selected => params[:pid] %>
```

Comment: without params,  `options_for_select` is better way.
It is good for any situation, good for form edit too.

Comment: Here is the KEY:   LOOK at your function (options_for_select() vs f.select. Remember these are different functions.

Answer (score 148):

Use the right attribute of the current instance (e.g. `@work.project_id`):

```
<%= f.select :project_id, options_for_select(..., @work.project_id) %>
```

Comment: This is the best answer because it works with `select_tag` too. Thanks it really helped me too.

Comment: Also you can try `options_for_select(..., f.object.project_id )`

Comment: Thanks so much!  All the other accepted answers don't say how to select via variable.

Answer (score 59):

Rails 3.0.9

```
select options_for_select([value1, value2, value3], default)
```

Comment: I couldn't figure this solution out until I noticed your closing bracket around the values array **BEFORE** the comma that separates your default value... I missed this bracket here `value3], default`

Comment: I tried a half dozen answers and passing the default to options_for_select was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
    <%= f.select :project_id, @project_select, :selected => f.object.project_id %>
```

Comment: Using Rails 4, the `params[:pid]` did not work, but your example did.

Comment: This worked for me as I'm using a partial inside "f.fields_for"
Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

if params[:pid] is a string, which if it came from a form, it is, you'll probably need to use

```rb
params[:pid].to_i
```

for the correct item to be selected in the select list

Comment: This answer helped me pinpoint my issue. My select box is dynamic and pulling a collection from the database. I was trying to populate the default selection by a title, not an id of the item. This answer helped me see that issue, and once I populated my `@project` variable with an id from the database table, instead of a title, this code worked appended onto the back of the `form.select` helper: `selected: @project` Thank you @danengle

Answer (score 10):

I've found solution and I found that I'm pretty unexperienced in RoR.

Inside the controller that manages view described above add this:

```
@work.project_id = params[:pid] unless params[:pid].nil?
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<%= f.select :project_id, @project_select, :selected => params[:pid] %>
```

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get this to work and found that I needed to add the "selected" html attribute not only to the correct `<option>` tag but *also* to the `<select>` tag. [MDN's docs on the selected attribute of the select tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) say:

> **selected** - Boolean attribute indicates that a specific option can be initially selected.

That means the code should look like:

```
f.select :project_id, options_for_select(@project_select, default_val), html: {selected: true}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= f.select :project_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@project_select,) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its already explained, Will try to give an example

let the select list be

```
select_list = { eligible: 1, ineligible: 0 }
```

So the following code results in

```
<%= f.select :to_vote, select_list %>

<select name="to_vote" id="to_vote">
  <option value="1">eligible</option>
  <option value="0">ineligible</option>
</select>
```

So to make a option selected by default we have to use **selected: value**.

```
<%= f.select :to_vote, select_list, selected: select_list.can_vote? ? 1 : 0 %>
```

if **can_vote?** returns true it sets **selected: 1** then the first value will be selected else second.

```
select name="driver[bca_aw_eligible]" id="driver_bca_aw_eligible">
  <option value="1">eligible</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="0">ineligible</option>
</select>
```

if the select options are just a array list instead of hast then the selected will be just the value to be selected for example if

```
select_list = [ 'eligible', 'ineligible' ]
```

now the selected will just take

```
<%= f.select :to_vote, select_list, selected: 'ineligible' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mike Bethany's answer above worked to set a default value when a new record was being created and still have the value the user selected show in the edit form.  However, I added a model validation and it would not let me submit the form.  Here's what worked for me to have a model validation on the field and to show a default value as well as the value the user selected when in edit mode.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :project_id, 'my project id', class: "control-label" %><br>
    <% if @work.new_record? %>
      <%= f.select :project_id, options_for_select([['Yes', true], ['No', false]], true), {}, required: true, class: "form-control" %><br>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.select :project_id, options_for_select([['Yes', true], ['No', false]], @work.project_id), {}, required: true, class: "form-control" %><br>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

model validation

```
  validates :project_id, presence: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could set the :project_id attribute in the controller, since the first argument of f.select pulls that particular attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If try to print the f object, then you will see that there is f.object that can be probed for getting the selected item (applicable for all rails version > 2.3)

```
logger.warn("f #{f.object.inspect}")
```

so, use the following script to get the proper selected option:

```
:selected => f.object.your_field
```

Answer (score -2):

This should work for you. It just passes `{:value => params[:pid] }` to the html_options variable.

```
<%= f.select :project_id, @project_select, {}, {:value => params[:pid] } %>
```

Comment: but it won't select appropriate item in select :S