# Rails select helper - set default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

Rails 2.3.11

I *did* read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623458/rails-select-helper-default-selected-value-how), but it's not working for me.

I would like the default option for this selection box to be the `event_id` passed through the URL.

```
f.select :event_id, @events, :selected => url_args["event_id"]
```

An example `@events` is`[["SC 2 Tournament", 195], ["Obstacle Course", 196], ["Mortal Combat", 197]]`

The following also didn't work:

- adding ".to_i" to "url_args["event_id"
- using options_for_select(@events, url_args["event_id"]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a lot easier if you use the collection_select helper:

```
f.collection_select :event_id, @events, :id, :name
```

Then to select the default option (and have that be selected on pageload), you can simply assign it to whatever Object it is that the form is for within the controller. eg like this:

```
def new
   @events = Event.all
   @thing = Thing.new(:event => @events.first)
end
```

I'm not sure where your `url_args` comes from, but I'm guessing it's probably from a param in the URL, in which case you can do this:

```
Thing.new(:event_id => params[:event_id])
```

One last thing - `collection_select` won't quite work with `@events` as you've specified it, as you're using a nested Array, when it's expecting an Array of Objects that it can call `id` and `name` on in order to retrieve the values and display text for the select options. To fix that, simply redefine `@events` within your controller, using one of the ActiveRecord finders, such as `Event.all` or `Event.find(..)`.

Make sense?

Comment: I've never used collections before, so I might look into those later.  I was able to fix my issue simply by swapping my custom `url_args` method for `params`, like so:

<%= f.select :event_id, @events, :selected => params[:event_id].to_i %>