# Rails' select tag helper not selecting existing value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using a select helper tag for a form in Rails 3.2.14:

```
<%= f.label :male, 'Gender' %>
<%= f.select :male, [['Girl', 0], ['Boy', 1]]  %>
```

The `Girl` and `Boy` menu items show up in the drop down, but `Boy` is never selected even if `male` in the database is set to `1`. `male` is actually a `boolean` value in `schema.rb`.

How do I get the `f.select` tag to automatically select a `Boy` if `male` is `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to call `options_for_select`, this is where you can define which option is selected. Example:

```
options = options_for_select [['Girl', 0], ['Boy', 1]], 1
f.select :male, options
```

Will output the select tag, its options, and Boy will be selected.

--

You can take a look at `options_from_collection_for_select` also, originally designed to be used with record collections, like:

```
options_from_collection_for_select @users, :id, :name
```

To generate options with `id` as value and `name` as text. `options_from_collection_for_select` can basically be used anywhere

```
coll = %w[cheese garlic]
options_from_collection_for_select coll, :to_s, :humanize
```

Will also work

Comment: I did need `options_for_select`, I played with that, but the problem was that I needed to use `resource.male ? 1 : 0` for the 2nd parameter to `options_for_select`. I didn't know I could use `resource.attribute` (using Devise).

Answer (score 0):

try this,

> f.object.male %>

get more options from this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623458/rails-select-helper-default-selected-value-how)