# Rails select helper setting default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, html-helper

Controller

```
def edit
@folder = Folder.find(params[:id])
@parents = Folder.all.where(:user_id => current_user).map{|u| [ u.name, u.id ]}
end
```

View

```
<%= form_for(:folder, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @folder.id}) do |f| %>

    <table summary="Folder form fields">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Parent folder:</th>
        <td>
        <%= f.select(:parent_id, options_for_select(@parents) )%></td>
      </tr>
</table>...
```

How to set a default value in select helper with a folder's parent_id ?
I've tried options_for_select(@parents, DEFAULT VALUE HERE) , also :selected => VALUE in a different places, no result. Please help

Comment: Try `<%= f.select(:parent_id, options_for_select(@parents,@parents.project_id) )%>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails select helper - Default selected value, how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623458/rails-select-helper-default-selected-value-how)

Comment: I've checked that already, yours doesnt work. I need to bind that list with a current folder parent_id value

Comment: This one `<%= f.select(:parent_id, options_for_select(@parents),:selected => f.object.parent_id) %>`?

Comment: Pavan you are the one who always give advices which are doesn't help ))) have you tested it by yourself ?))))

Answer (score 1):

If you pass the folder object to `form_tag` then Rails should work out the default value automatically. You also shouldnt need to use `options_for_select` as the `select` form helper takes an array of options.

```
<%= form_for(@folder, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @folder.id}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select(:parent_id, @parents) %>
<% end %>
```

Also, specifying the URL in `form_tag` is redundant if you use RESTful routes.

Answer (score 0):

In a form_for, the default value is the value assigned to the object the form is built on. That means if you want the select to default to certain value, you need to set the `parent_id` attribute in the controller to that value.

```
@folder.parent_id = 23 # the default value
```