# Ruby select tag options default value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select, html-helper

I have an issues with select tag default value.
**Controller code:**

```
def edit
@folder = Folder.find(params[:id])
@parents = Folder.all.where(:user_id => current_user).map{|u| [ u.name, u.id ]}
end
```

@parents returns [["tt", 2], ["test", 3], ["test", 4], ["gg", 5], ["test", 1], ["gg", 6], ["tt", 7], ["test 2", 8], ["test 2", 9], ["HH", 10], ["Default", 16], ["Default 33", 17], ["XX", 18]]

**My View code:**

```
<%= form_for(:folder, :url => {:action => 'update', :id => @folder.id}) do |f| %>

    <table summary="Folder form fields">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field(:name) %></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Parent folder:</th>
        <td>
        <%= f.select(:parent_id, options_for_select(@parents))%></td>
      </tr>

      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    </table>
...
```

Select displays folder names correctly, but how to make a default value? I've tried different approaches already, still no result. :selected => value and options_for_select(@parents, value) doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: Duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726377/rails-select-helper-setting-default-value#comment38371589_24726377

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails select helper - Default selected value, how?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623458/rails-select-helper-default-selected-value-how)

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

This should help you..

```
<%= f.select :parent_id, options_for_select(@parents,''), {:include_blank => true, :default => nil}, :style=>'**any-inline-css-for-this-select-box**',:onchange=>"any_js_function();"%>
```