# How to insert selected value from f.select in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I want to insert selected value from select tag into data base when i submit form.

The problems is all value select from select tag, But when i submit form then only first value is always inserting into data base, not selected value.

My **_form.html.erb** file

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label">Requirement Type</label>
  <div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> </span>
     <%= f.select :job_types, Settings.job_types_for_job_posting.to_a.map { |w| [w.humanize, w] }, {}, class: "form-control" %>
   </div>
</div>
```

My Enum Define in **setting.yml** file

```
job_types_for_job_posting: [Contract, Permanent, On Demand, Internal]
```

My **jobs_controller.rb** file is

```
    def create
    @job = current_user.job_postings.build(params_value)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save
        add_or_update_skills
        format.json { render json: { result: true } }
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Job is posted successfully' }
      else
        format.json { render json: { result: false } }
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

    params.require(:job_posting).permit(:title, :description, :salary_from, :salary_to, :experience, :experienceto,
                                        :expected,:key,:sourcing,:client_id, :job_assignment,:status, :no_of_opening, :location, :designation, :responsibilities, :job_skills, :industry_id, :functional_area_id, :role_category_id, :job_role_id, :job_types)
  end
```

When I am posing new job then every time insert only "Contract" means 0. Can any body tell me, Where am i wrong...

Comment: Could you please check the source code of your `select` I think your code generates wrong html

Comment: I have checked and try but i got same issue, I have done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623458/rails-select-helper-default-selected-value-how, but problems is not solved....

Comment: See answer, should fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(without having tested it) I think your line should read:

```
<%= f.select(:job_types, Settings.job_types_for_job_posting.to_a.collect.with_index { |w, i| [w.humanize, i] }, {}, class: "form-control") %>
```

The index of the array is supposed to be your value, right?

Comment: Thank you so much, Please tell me any books, sites and other source for learning ruby on rails. I have so many problems in ruby on rails like- ajax, JavaScript, J query implementation, Flow of execution etc... please help me where can i read and implement these whole things....