# Define the default value of a drop down menu from a class variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a list of books categories on my db. I can get the value of them inside my controller like this:

```
@categories = Book.uniq.pluck(:category) #programming, networking, infrastructure
```

And then, I can pass the value in the view to a drop down menu like this:

```
<%= s.select :category, options_for_select(@categories) %>
```

**So, my question:**

How I can define to be the selected default value of my drop down menu, the second value of the `@categories`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) about *options_for_select*, the second parameter is the selected value:

```
options_for_select(container, selected = nil)
```

So, the answer according to my question is:

```
<%= s.select :category, options_for_select(@categories, @categories.second) %>
```

And of course, you can also try with: [options_from_collection_for_select](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_from_collection_for_select)

**Note:** Some credits also to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2434434/2954267

Answer (score 0):

You can define the default value by using the `:selected` option:

```
<%= s.select :category, :selected => params[:id] %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know this. I just need the answer corresponding to my specific situation within my two questions.

Comment: Have you tried @categories.second? Or alternatively, @categories[1] or Category.all.second?

Comment: Sorry, but does not works. Always appear the first value selected, and I want the second or the third.